# Not able to register a service on Eureka server in Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry

I am trying to set up am Eureka server in Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF) using a user provided sevice.
I can get the server to work ok in local, but not working in PCF. The only difference I can see from the logs is that the status code from PCF is NA, while it is 204 (Success) in local.  Is there any settings to be done in PCF for this to work.

**Local**
2017-06-23 15:42:50 DEBUG c.n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient - Jersey HTTP POST http://localhost:8761/eureka//apps/DISCOVERY-SERVER with instance EULN-D148177.ent.ad.hosturl:discovery-server:8761; statusCode=204

**PCF**
2017-06-23T16:24:57.094+01:00 [APP/0] [OUT] 2017-06-23 15:24:57 DEBUG c.n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient - Jersey HTTP POST http://eureka:changeme@nt_eureka-server.apps.system.pcf.hosturl/eureka//apps/SERVICE with instance 946be047-e1b6-49b5-6430-3b31f49b8731; statusCode=N/A
2

POM File from service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.nt.servicediscovery</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you paste pom.xml file from service app?

Comment: Can you please provide more information, such as the versions you are using and the configuration used in each instance?

Comment: I tried the same code in Pivotal Web Services (public version) and i am able to register the service in Eureka. So it looks the port 8761 is not open in our internal version of Pivotal Cloud Foundry. Have raised a request to open this port, will try again once the port is open.

Comment: @KumareshBabu When i update the POM file as suggested, the app is crashing when i push it to Cloud Foundry. Error message : 2017-07-03T12:17:42.511+01:00 [APP/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean' defined in class path resource [io/pivotal/spring/cloud/service/eureka/EurekaInstanceAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaInstanceConfigBean.afterPropertiesSet()V

Comment: Changed the spring-cloud-services version to 1.5 from 1.3 and the app is now getting loaded correctly in cloud foundry, but it is still not registering the service in Eureka. So i think the URL i am providing is not correct. This is  the default zone i am using: eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${vcap.services.discovery-service.credentials.uri:http://localhost}:${PORT:8761}/eureka

Comment: Can you remove eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${vcap.services.discov‌​ery-service.credenti‌​als.uri:localhost}:$‌​{PORT:8761}/eureka from property file? Usually I will not provide info to property file. Because spring boot creates bean for eureka server(io.pivotal) and it will authenticate to pivotal eureka server.

Comment: Finally got it working. I have used underscore in the route (DNS) names...once i changed it to '-', my service was getting registered to Eureka Server.

Answer (score 1):

Remove dependency from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add Service Registry dependency provided by Pivotal

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add Spring Cloud services dependencies under `<dependencyManagement>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```